# How measure Hilt/Dagger build time on my android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-hilt

Using google `Hilt` or `Dagger` for **Android Projects** can bring some increase on the build time.

But I would love to have some data of how much exactly the build takes with `Hilt` and `without Hilt`.

I have a multi-module project without hilt and one branch with hilt.

**How to measure for sure the **build/compilation** time and be sure of how much Hilt take.?**

I'm expecting something like:

```
Build without Hilt = 2m
Build with Hilt = 3m (Hilt took 45s)
```

Maybe I will see a decrease, *not sure*, but this is what I want to analyse.

**All builds should be from zero without cache.**
The goal is to improve compilation time for the devs in the day to day basis

Thanks!

Comment: Also looking for the same help , did you figured it out ? . If yes , please help with with this

Comment: I came across a repo which helped to compare all available Di library performance : https://github.com/Sloy/android-dependency-injection-performance  & 2 blogs supporting Dagger/Hilt : https://proandroiddev.com/how-dagger-hilt-and-koin-differ-under-the-hood-c3be1a2959d7 &  https://medium.com/@phamduy.uit/dependency-injection-can-koin-replace-dagger-from-simple-to-serious-projects-ae358feb8585